# Is it possible to find and store element's location by text in selenium ide?

Tags: selenium-ide

I need to create the element and then delete it. Is there a way to find the element by it's text after it was created?
The xpath of the element is //div[@id='mif-tree-6']/span/span[3].

Answer (score 0):

You can use xpath for it for example. Like:

```
//div[@id='mif-tree-6']//span[contains(text(),'your_text_here')]
```

**UPDATE**

Please provide an example of your html. It is possible to find a parent of your element with xpath and after that to find all the childs. For example your html =

```
<div id='lol'>
  <div>first_item</div>
  <div>second_item</div>
  <div>third_element</div>
</div>
```

You get an array of elements with xpath =

```
//div[contains(text(),'first_')]/../div
```

So you can do something like:

```
click | //div[contains(text(),'first_')]/../div[2]
```

**BUT** if there are a lot of brothers-elements to find by text of one sibling it will be necessary to use loop to get every of them.

Once again. If you will provide full information about what are you doing and an example of your html it will be much easier to suggest.

Comment: Thanks for the helpful answer. After exploring the issue, what helped me is //span[contains(text(),'My text')]. Thanks a lot!!! Is there a way to store the xpath location of the element?

Comment: Explain please what do you mean "to store the xpath location of the element?" What do you want to receive?

Comment: I need to receive the xpath of the element from clicking on it or by text the element contains

Comment: //span[contains(text(),'your_text_here')] is xpath already. If you want to get some suggested xpath for non-interactive element click Select button on the selenium IDE window. Click on the element on the page. Check dropdown with suggestions. But as I've said //span[contains(text(),'your_text_here')] is already an xpath.

Comment: I want to use next element after the one containing text, for this I need to use the full xpath with indexes. For example this is the xpath of the element Group //div[@id='mif-tree-8']/span/span[3]. I need to click on existing group by its text, receive the full xpath and move to next group, which will be for example //div[@id='mif-tree-9']/span/span[3]